# I want to make a photo-trap for wildlife

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, microprocessor, video, development

I want to make a photo-trap with extra features.

I tried using a Raspberry Pi for this, but I could not start the system in under 4 seconds.

When other photo-traps detect motion, they start recording in less than 1 second. They also offer up to 6 months of battery life.

I want to make a device similar to this, but it will send me a data from some sensors over wireless. The products on the market do not do that.

In summary, I need a processor or device that can be started in less than 1 second, suitable for battery use, and where I can record HD and configure its software.

I would like to receive suggestions and ideas from people knowledgeable about this subject.

Edit:
I turned off everything possible in raspberry pi. I also open the system with a processor and sensor group, but the raspberry pi cannot open before 5 seconds. This is too late for what I want to catch. Of course, how can the photo-traps sold in the market open up to 200-300ms with a 6-month battery life and start recording?
[image]

Comment: what is `mouth features`? ... i think that the translation got messed up

Comment: Can you explain what a photocap or photo-trap does? I think the translation is wrong.

Comment: I think this might be a wildlife camera.

Comment: Is "mouth" a mistranslation of "opening"? I think the best word in that case would actually be "start up".

Comment: Putting your processor into deep sleep with an interrupt to wake would be faster than powering it up from cold.  A lot of processors use negligible current in deep sleep mode.

Comment: Sorry I corrected the translation a little. and the right wildlife camera.Developer boards like Arduino and esp have a deepsleep mode but they don't have the capacity to record hd.Since boards like raspberry pi are also running linux, there is no deepsleep mode and the bootings are at least 4sec.(as far as I know)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please keep in mind that seeking product recommendations are considered off topic here. Nevertheless a short hint: RasPi is basically an industrial PC running a full fledged Linux fostering hundreds of feautures you don't need. Think of another embedded platforms like arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my few thoughts.

- Raspberry pi needs long time to wake-up. There is no deep sleep mode support as far as I know too.
- The unwanted interfaces can be disabled, including GPU for example.. you can also keep it in standby mode.
- You can think of using a beefier battery pack.
- Think of also solar power option if feasible.
- You can use the Arduino Board or a ultra low peer board to early detect the presence (do not know your case exactly but if it am option, it can give a heads-up to Pi to boot up).

Comment: What is the battery capacity and what is your standby load?